# How to reference foreign key from more than one column (Inconsistent values)

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I Have table three tables:

**The first one is emps:**

```
create table emps (id number primary key , name nvarchar2(20));
```

**The second one is cars:**

```
create table cars (id number primary key , car_name varchar2(20));
```

**The third one is accounts:**

```
create table accounts (acc_id number primary key, woner_table nvarchar2(20) , 
                   woner_id number references emps(id) references cars(id));
```

Now I Have these values for selected tables:

**Emps:**

```
ID         Name
-------------------
1          Ali
2          Ahmed
```

**Cars:**

```
ID           Name
------------------------
107          Camery 2016
108          Ford 2012
```

**I Want to**
Insert values in **accounts** table so its data should be like this:

**Accounts:**

```
Acc_no         Woner_Table     Woner_ID
------------------------------------------
11013          EMPS           1
12010          CARS           107
```

I tried to perform this SQL statement:

```
Insert into accounts (acc_id , woner_table , woner_id) values (11013,'EMPS',1);
```

**BUT** I get this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (HR.SYS_C0016548) violated - parent key not found.
```

This error occurs because the value of `woner_id` column doesn't exist in cars table.

My work require link tables in this way.

**How Can I Solve This Problem Please ?!..**

**Mean:** How can I reference tables in previous way and Insert values without this problem ?..

Comment: The approach is flawed from the start. You shouldn't have information about "emps" and "cars" in the same table. An "emp" may have a spouse (husband or wife), or a monthly salary, etc.; a car can't. A car may have a price, or a color; an emp does not. WHY do you need a table or view like the one you described?

Comment: the above tables are just to explain what I need. @mathguy

Comment: So, is it more like you have two different employee tables and you want to combine them together? (Like, one shows the employees in one location and the other the employees in a different location?) That would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-of relationships are tricky in SQL.  With your data structure here is one possibility:

```
create table accounts (
    acc_id number primary key,
    emp_id number references emps(id),
    car_id number references car(id),
    id as (coalesce(emp_id, car_id)),
    woner_table as (case when emp_id is not null then 'Emps'
                         when car_id is not null then 'Cars'
                    end),
    constraint chk_accounts_car_emp check (emp_id is null or car_id is null)
);
```

You can fetch the `id` in a select.  However, for the insert, you need to be explicit:

```
Insert into accounts (acc_id , emp_id)
    values (11013, 1);
```

Note:  Earlier versions of Oracle do not support virtual columns, but you can do almost the same thing using a view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, But my problem is that: I have about 5 tables that I want to reference to accounts table, and if I used like this way that means I will add more columns to the accounts table, and this is what I am trying to avoid. @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Your approach should be changed such that your Account table contains two foreign key fields - one for each foreign table.  Like this:

```
create table accounts (acc_id number primary key,
                       empsId number references emps(id),
                       carsId number references cars(id));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, But my problem is that: I have about 5 tables that I want to reference to accounts table, and if I used like this way that means I will add more columns to the accounts table, and this is what I am trying to avoid. @STLDeveloper

Comment: As @Joe pointed out in his answer, to do this in such a way as to use only one column to hold multiple foreign keys and another column to hold the table name to which the key value belongs will  make working with this database structure very difficult. Your code will need to create and execute SQL statements dynamically. Unless you're an expert SQL developer, I would strongly encourage you to **not** use that approach.

Comment: Thank you so much I don't have problem in using dynamic SQL. thanks again @STLDeveloper

Comment: One benefit of the 2 cols approach is enforcement of a not null column for the FK - which you lose with the multi-FK col approach. In my mind still not reason to use it, but it is a nice benefit. Also, the multi-col approach will sometimes have a 3rd col to indicate datatype of the FK col. Arguably, it's a derived value and can be looked, up, but putting that in can save effort.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, most straightforward method to do this is as STLDeveloper says, add additional FK columns, one for each table. This also bring along with it the benefit of the database being able to enforce Referential Integrity.

BUT, if you choose not to do, then the next option is to use one FK column for the the FK values and a second column to indicate what table the value refers to. This keeps the number of columns small = 2 max, regardless of number of tables with FKs. But, this significantly increases the programming burden for the application logic and/or PL/SQL, SQL. And, of course, you completely lose Database enforcement of RI.